# BGE: Move character from Scene1 to Scene2 and keeping the character to Scene2

Tags: python, game-engine, logic-bricks, scene

How can the character (red star) go thru a door from Scene1 to Scene2?
Scene 1 is the current one and Scene2 is to be loaded after the character go thru the door.
Scene1 is the exterior and Scene2 is a building.

I've created a  [blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33045) as per coments but is not working.
[image: Description]

Comment: You could add a cube that has static physics, make it invisible, put it in the door, and put a logic brick `Collision` on the cube. Add a property to the player called something like `change_scene` set the `collision` type to property and enter that name. Then hook that up to an `And` and then to a `Set Scene`

Comment: To make it simple, I just want to change the scenes in game from outside to inside and vice versa, the ideea is not to load all the scene from one go.

Comment: This isn't loading all the scenes, all this would do is change the scene when you passed through the doorway.

Comment: Thanks BlendingJake. And can I keep the character in Scene2?

Answer (score 2):

You wont be able to actually "transfer" the player object in-game.  But you can create an instance of the player in each scene beforehand.

1. Move the player to (0, 0, 0) on a non-visible layer
2. Add it to a new group.  I named mine "Player"
3. Do Shift+A -> Group Instance -> Player in each scene that needs to contain the player.

[image: Creating a group object]

This method will not copy properties that have changed since the scene started.  You'll likely need a Python script for that.

**EDIT - Quick example of transferring specific properties between scenes**

**1.** Run this on your player right before changing scenes

```
import bge

def saveProps(cont):
    own = cont.owner

    props = {}
    props['name_of_property'] = own['name_of_property']
    props['another_property'] = own['another_property']
    # ... etc

    bge.logic.player_props = props

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
    saveProps(cont)
```

**2.** And run this when a scene first loads, basically the first script in reverse.

```
import bge

def getProps(cont):
    own = cont.owner

    try:
        props = bge.logic.player_props
    except:
        # Props dict not defined.  This was likely the first scene.
        return

    own['name_of_property'] = props['name_of_property']
    own['another_property'] = props['another_property']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
    getProps(cont)
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there any tutorial for properties transfer?

Comment: Added an example of property transfer to the answer